# Problems Streaming files

Tags: c#, stream, zip

i was reading files inside a ZipFolder

```
var zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zipFile)
{
    if (!zipEntry.IsFile)
    {
        continue;  // Ignore directories
    }

    var entryFileName = zipEntry.Name.ToLower();
    var zipStream = zipFile.GetInputStream(zipEntry);

    else if(entryFileName.EndsWith(".png"))
    {
        previews.Add(entryFileName, zipStream);                    
    }
    else
    {
        documents.Add(entryFileName, zipStream);                    
    }
}
```

and i was planning to Save those zipstream into a new FileStream 
but then when i'm validating the stream

```
if (stream.Length == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("stream");

using (var newFile = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Create))
{
    stream.CopyTo(newFile);
}
```

i got the exception because stream.lengt is equal to 0

i wonder if there's a better way to do this or why this stream isn't working

Comment: You say you got *the* exception, but you're not saying which exception you're getting. Or are you saying you got the ArgumentException you're throwing? If so, you need to verify that the Length property is actually used for those streams, as it might have to unzip the entire stream before knowing its size, so it might always return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZIP files not always saves their length to themself so Length property can not work. Try stream.CanRead property.